# Spring Boot Security OAuth - handle InternalAuthenticationServiceException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

My Spring Boot OAuth REST application returns "401 Unauthorized" status when the database connection failure(Spring Security throws InternalAuthenticationServiceException ). 
It's strange, and I need to change status to "500 Internal server error" that client can provide some adequate description, like "service is not available".

If I use WebResponseExceptionTranslator then I can catch response, but if I change HTTP status, it works only when the database active. If the database is shutdown, then I get "401 Unauthorized" again.

How can I solve this problem most gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which level the exception is thrown, you might want to add exception handler to your login controller:

```
@ExceptionHandler(InternalAuthenticationServiceException.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
   // convert exception to 500, add logging and
}
```

Learn more about exception handling here:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure that @ExceptionHandler is the way. Unfortunately I have not LoginController, and all authorization requests handles by spring-oauth-library.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by adding "try catch" around jdbcTemplate request in my custom UserDetailService.

```
protected List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {

       try {    

            userDetailsList = this.getJdbcTemplate().query( USERS_BY_USERNAME, new String[]{username}, 
                    new RowMapper() {
                        public UserDetails mapRow( ResultSet rs, int rowNum ) throws SQLException {
                        String username = rs.getString( 1 );

                        /* etc. map user fields */

                        return new SecurityUser( username, /* other params... */ );
                    }
            });

        } catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException e){

            logger.error( "UserDetailService SQL error: " + e.getMessage(), e );
        } 

        return userDetailsList; 
}
```

And then I check InternalAuthenticationServiceException
by WebResponseExceptionTranslator and change response status.

It seems that when I catch CannotGetJdbcConnectionException then something ruins in chain. It works, but I will leave my question open, maybe someone can offer a more clear solution.